# Validate XML against custom property definition language in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml

I need to write a Ruby script to validate XML responses against a master XML schema template.

Say for example, an example XML response coming from the backend for a controller is:

```
<a>
  <ID>TestID</ID>
  <Name>NameTest</Name>
  <Description/>
  <DisplayName>DisplayNameTest</DisplayName>
</a>
```

and I have an XML schema template which has one of the section looks like:

```
<Object name = "a">
  <property name = "ID" optional="true"/>
  <property name = "Name" optional="true"/>
  <property name="visibility" />
  <property name="Description" optional="true" />
  <property name="DisplayName" optional="true" />  
</Object>
```

Things I want to validate against the schema template is:

1. If the optional attribute tag is set to true, this tag is mandatory and must be present in the response.
2. The tag orders need to follow the tag orders in the schema template.

If either of the condition doesn't comply, return false.

Some piece of the codes I have now is (probably there are a lot of ways to better do this):

```
response_xml = REXML::Document.new(response_xml)
response_xml_root = response_xml.root.name.to_s.chomp
xml_api_meta = REXML::Document.new(File.read('Schema.xml'))
response_xml_array = response_xml.root.elements.to_a.collect { |e| e.name }

@api_meta_array = []
xml_api_meta.elements.each('ApiMeta/Object') do |element|
  if element.attributes["name"] == response_xml_root
    element.elements.each do |children|
      @api_meta_array.push children.attributes["name"]
    end
  end
end
```

My idea is to collect all the tag names from response XML and push them into an array `@response_xml_array` and do the same thing for the schema and push all the tag found in an array `@api_meta_array`.

How can I validate the sequence and whether it is optional or not?

Answer (score 4):

If you have xml, why don't use use an [Xml Schema](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema) xsd file to validate the xml?  Then you can use Nokogiri for instance to validate the xml.  http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Schema.html .  This is much easier than writing your own validator.

Relax NG is another schema definition language.

Is your "XML schema template" in a defined language? (Forgive my ignorance if it is obvious.)  If so, libraries supporting the language should be able to validate xml using the schema.  If not, you might be able to translate it to xml schema